# How to remove dropdown from opencart 2.2 breadcrumb?

Tags: php, css, opencart2.x

I am using opencart v2.2.0 and have the code below for the breadcrumb.  This breadcrumb show the categories as a dropdown.  How can I edit this breadcrumb to remove that dropdown and just show the right categories and sub categories?

Here is a screenshot of how it works: 
[breadcrumb screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6PUx.jpg)

And here is the code:

```
<div class="breadcrumb <?php if($theme_options->get( 'breadcrumb_layout' ) == 2) { echo 'fixed'; } else { echo 'full-width'; } ?>">
<div class="background-breadcrumb"></div>
<div class="background">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="pattern">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    $next_cat_id = 0;
                    foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) {
                        $cats = array();
                        if($registry->get('request')->get['route'] == 'product/product' || $registry->get('request')->get['route'] == 'product/category'){
                            if($i == 1 ){
                                $cats = $theme_options->getCategories(0);
                            }else if($next_cat_id > 0 && count($breadcrumbs)-1 > $i){
                                $cats = $theme_options->getCategories($next_cat_id);
                            }
                        }


                    ?>
                    <li class="item <?php echo !empty($cats) ? 'dropdown' : '';?>">
                        <a <?php echo !empty($cats) ? 'class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"' : '';?>
                            href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php if($breadcrumb['text'] != '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>') { echo $breadcrumb['text']; } else { if($theme_options->get( 'home_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '') { echo $theme_options->get( 'home_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ); } else { echo 'Home'; } } ?></a>

                        <?php if(!empty($cats)):?>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <?php foreach($cats as $cat):?>
                                <?php if($cat['label'] == $breadcrumb['text']):?>
                                    <?php $next_cat_id = $cat['category_id']; continue; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $cat['href'] ?>"><?php echo $cat['label'] ?></a>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </li>
                    <?php $i++; } ?>
                </ul>
 <!--                   <h1 id="title-page"><?php echo $heading_title; ?>
                    <?php if(isset($weight)) { if ($weight) { ?>
                    &nbsp;(<?php echo $weight; ?>)
                    <?php } } ?>
                </h1>
                <div class="strip-line"></div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No Answer Please ?!!

Comment: This is not core opencart code. 
This is code of custom theme. 
Analyzing the code what I can say is:
Comment the line below:  
$cats = $theme_options->getCategories($next_cat_id);

All codes are written from custom theme. By commenting above it may not go to next level category, only show the top category.

Comment: ya , i know its a custom code, i dont want to prevent go next level category , i need just to remove the dropdown , and work normally like the default opencart breadcrumb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know where this code is so be careful with closing div and other html.
As I per code I have remove other level and dropdown. I considered $breadcrumbs array is returning as of default code. If they have changed it then need to change in controller part also. Hope following will works.

```
<div class="breadcrumb <?php if($theme_options->get( 'breadcrumb_layout' ) == 2) { echo 'fixed'; } else { echo 'full-width'; } ?>">
<div class="background-breadcrumb"></div>
<div class="background">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="pattern">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a
                                href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php if($breadcrumb['text'] != '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>') { echo $breadcrumb['text']; } else { if($theme_options->get( 'home_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '') { echo $theme_options->get( 'home_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ); } else { echo 'Home'; } } ?></a>    
                        </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                </ul>
<!--                   <h1 id="title-page"><?php echo $heading_title; ?>
                    <?php if(isset($weight)) { if ($weight) { ?>
                    &nbsp;(<?php echo $weight; ?>)
                    <?php } } ?>
                </h1>
                <div class="strip-line"></div>-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i implemented your code and gave me this as the screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/504oj9/9

Comment: Please remove $i++;

Comment: Just for my hard work, if you vote my answer then it will improve my profile  :)

Yes, but that takes little more time. Your theme is also custom theme so I may not be able to know how they are coded